# SubmitChanges() updates database in bin folder

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, local-database, submitchanges

My code and the `Linq to sql` function `SubmitChanges` are working, but when using a `local database` a copy of the database in the `bin` folder is updated and not the primary database. So the changes aren't shown on a new query. If I re-connect the database but don't load it as `local` same problem - the primary database isn't updated, but now I can't figure out which one is (tks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586291/why-isnt-my-submitchanges-working-in-linq-to-sql)).

What setting for a local db or how do I use a non-local database to show changes on a new query of the database?

```
Dim DATA As New lnqPolarisDataContext
        Dim newBOOK As New BOOK()
        newBOOK.ID = 14
        newBOOK.LEG = 11
            newBOOK.P_C = "C"
            newBOOK.STRATEGY = "STRADDLE"
            newBOOK.STRIKE = 999
            newBOOK.CONTRACT = "XXX"

            DATA.BOOKs.InsertOnSubmit(newBOOK)
            DATA.SubmitChanges()

   ... new query doesn't show these changes
```

maybe [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx) is the best method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **real** solution in my opinion would be to put your database **on the server** where it belongs - after all, SQL Server **is** a server-based solution, not a file-based "database".....

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: Thanks Marc_s I'll take a look. I haven't worked with a server based db yet.